# why this loop is running only once 2.0 remake

Tags: python, list, loops

Why is this first loop running only once?

I only know that this line is what causes this:

```py
unchecked = text.pop(0)
```

how to fix it?

```py
def search(text):
    text=list(text)
    pat=[]
    history=[]
    for char in text:
        print(char)
        negative=[]
        pat.append(char)
        for i in range(int(len(text)/len(pat))):
            for char in pat:
                unchecked = text.pop(0)
                if unchecked == char:
                    history.append(unchecked)
```

Comment: you are modifying the variable you are iterating. Don't do that. Instead of `text.pop(0)`, do `unchecked = text[0]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. You've only provided your `search` function but not the `text` argument you call it with

Comment: what were you expecting ?

Comment: Can you explain in words of few syllables what this code is trying to achieve? I ask especially as it doesn't return anything. Can I also remind you of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73664356/why-this-loop-running-only-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function by this code then it will work well

```
def search(text):
    text=list(text)
    pat=[]
    history=[]
    for char in text:
        print(char)
        negative=[]
        pat.append(char)
        temp = text.copy()
        for i in range(int(len(text)/len(pat))):
            for char in pat:
                unchecked = temp.pop(0)
                if unchecked == char:
                    history.append(unchecked)
```